# comma before "though" when ending a sentence — is it necessary?

Tags: punctuation, commas, sentence-ends

Two Oxford dictionaries contradict each other (see below).

In your opinion, is it necessary to use a comma before *though* when it ends a sentence?

> *Oxford Dictionary of English*
>
> I was hunting for work. Jobs were scarce though.

> *Concise Oxford English Dictionary*
>
> He was able to write, though.

Comment: I'd guess it's entirely optional since it's correct to use it and to omit it.

Comment: How does giving two non-identical examples constitute a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

When I started studying English, more years ago than I care to count, I was taught that, as an adverb at the end of a sentence, "though" should be preceded by a comma. That's the way I have always written it. A current search in mainstream dictionaries, however, shows that my teacher was only partially right. Most sources give examples of this adverb preceded or not by a comma.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/though?show=0&t=1422025704) we have the following examples, with and without a comma.

> - "I know we didn't win, but I was happy with how we played, though."
> - "It's hard work. I enjoy it though."

I've tried to find what n-gram shows, but the moment you add a comma you make it impossible to find such data.

Comment: There's no way to escape a comma, I suppose? Or perhaps ", though"?

Comment: @MattGutting In this particular case, you can escape the "comma" and it won't be  wrong. I will continue using it, though.

Comment: The first M-W is rather iffy, pairing 'but' and 'though' tautologically. I'd say that the longer the independent clause before the final 'though', the nearer the inclusion of the comma approaches to being a requirement. With short independent clauses, it can merely be used if one prefers the sentence to be read with a pause there. You may want a pause for reflection on Thursday (I enjoy it, though), but prefer a brisker, uninterrupted reading on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are correct but isn't providing clarity of what is meant the main purpose of using commas? (See [Adding Commas for Clarity](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000090.htm)) Omitting one before "though" at the end of a sentence does not change the meaning. That's one less character to type. So leave it out!